# Migrating tomcat war to glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I have a running war servlet in tomcat6. It works fine in tomcat. Now I need to migrate it to glassfish and it doesn't work.

First it show a big amount of problems (context, path null, etc) So I decided to create a new project in eclipse and copy all my classes in java and libraries to the new one.

Now I have a problem because I can upload the new .war to glassfish but servlet doesn't answer to my queries.

I think I have a problem with my glassfish-web.xml and almost sure with other things which I don't know.

The autogenerated glassfish-web.xml is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/TEST</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

And the path to one of my resources is this one: /students (class path) /listNames (method resource inside class)

So I guess I should use this url to access to my resource: localhost:port/nameOfMyWar/TEST/students/listNames

But it shows a white screen in my browser and log doesn't show anything.

What do I have to modify from a tomcat servlet project to adapt to a glassfish project? Is there a guide or some webpage with clues?

This is my actual web.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
              <display-name>SERVLET</display-name>
              <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
              </welcome-file-list>
              <servlet>
                <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
                <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                  <param-value>com.my.example.servlet</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
              </servlet>
              <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
              </servlet-mapping>
              <servlet>
                <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
                <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
              </servlet>
              <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
              </servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
              </servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
              </servlet-mapping>
              <servlet>
                <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
                <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
              </servlet>
              <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
              </servlet-mapping>
            </web-app>
```

Comment: I don't get any error. Just a white screen. I have got the war running on glassfish but I cannot access to the resources even when the server.log said that they were loaded. I got a nullpointerexception which is not given in tomcat. It is related to apache wink libraries. Could my problem comes from that? that I am using wink and not jax-rs?

Comment: Yes that is possible, anyway people can't guess this information. You have to provide more details (error messages, `web.xml`, `pom.xml`).

Comment: I added my web.xml. I don't have pom.xml or I am not able to find it